# DateOnly object gets default value when handing over to Test

Tags: c#, .net

Dear stackoverflow community

I have the problem that both DateOnly objects `today` and `inForceFrom` have the default value 1.1.0001 when the method gets called instead of the values 25.4.2016 and 26.4.2016.
Here the code:

```
    [DataTestMethod]
    [DynamicData(nameof(TestData), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
    public void Test(DateOnly today, DateOnly inForceFrom, Status expectedStatus)
    {
        // Test method body
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData()
    {
        yield return new object[] { new DateOnly(2016, 4, 25), new DateOnly(2016, 4, 26), Status.Status1};
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is an issue with MSTest when passing around `readonly struct`'s (was able to reproduce the behaviour with a custom one). Will try to investigate and submit bug report later but for know you can work around this issue by creating wrapper class for the test data:

```
public record MyTestData(DateOnly today, DateOnly  inForceFrom, Status expectedStatus);

public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData()
{
    yield return new object[] { new MyTestData(new DateOnly(2016, 4, 25), new DateOnly(2016, 4, 26), Status.Status1)};
}

[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(TestData), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void Test(MyTestData data)
{
    // Test method body
}
```

**UPD**

Created a [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/1693). Also discovered that for custom `readonly structs` switching to `init` properties (or using `readonly record struct`'s) makes the test infrastructure to work (see the repro repository attached in the issue).

Comment: did you raise this in the end?

Comment: @MarkAdamson TBH no. Will check again and raise later today.

Comment: thanks, I hit it today and had to do a similar workaround to the one you posted